# why doesn't this script work and...?

Tags: javascript

html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
<center>
<form>
 <select id="newLocation">
  <option value="1.jpg">index</option>
   <option value="script.js">posts</option>
   <option value="2.jpg" selected="selected">blog</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

javascript :

```
window.onload = startInit;

function startInit() {
document.getElementById("newLocation").selectedIndex = 0;
document.getElementById("newLocation").onchange = jumpPage;
}

function jumpPage() {
var newLoc = document.getElementById("newLocation");// what does this statement return ?
var newPage = newLoc.options[newLoc.getSelectedIndex].value;
if(newPage != "")
   window.location = newPage;
}
```

Why don't get to to new page i.e the value when i select an option from the combo box ?
Also what does `document.getElementById("newLocation");` this statement *(the first statement of the function jumpPage)* return ?

Comment: The usual way to diagnose things like this is debugging. Make test outputs using `console.log` or `alert()` to see what goes wrong at which point. That way, you can also find out for yourself what that line returns that you're asking about

Comment: @ Pekkai had tried that method but didn't understand the output.It returns `object HTML select element`. i didn't understand this.

Comment: If you really want to *learn* how to do this, then maybe ask a question about that. It would be much more productive  than somebody figuring out what the problem is in the current script

Comment: What's not to understand? If you get an element by ID, you're going to get the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var newPage = newLoc.options[newLoc.selectedIndex].value;
```

The statement

```
var newLoc = document.getElementById("newLocation");
```

just finds the DOM (HTML) element `<... id="newLocation" ...>`, i.e. your `<select id="newLocation">` .

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("newLocation")` will return you the SELECT object (i.e., the reference to your drop-down).

Regarding the JS, it has an error. You should change `newLoc.getSelectedIndex` to `newLoc.selectedIndex`.